# iText PDF library accessing ACRO fields with backslash

Tags: c#, itext

I encountered an iText exception writing to PDF form (developed by IRS using Adobe LiveCycle Designer) in particular a field named (topmostSubform[0].Page11[0].Header_SchH_Part2[0].a\.Average[0].c11_1[0])

**The "\"  character, hexadecimal value 0x5C, cannot be included in a name.**

The backslash is there correctly to escape period “.” in part “a.Average[0]” as opposed to be a path delimiter.

Anybody knows how to fix or avoid the issue?

I tried the name without the backslash but in that case the name cannot be found.

Comment: In AcroForms you cannot escape periods. They simply are forbidden in field names and used only to concatenate those names along the field hierarchy.

Comment: I know you can escape periods because I found a specification document about it.  Also, I am dealing with forms created by IRS using Adobe LiveCycle which allows to use periods and that is when iText library gets into trouble.